# How to get the id from all children on Angular-tree-component?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular-Tree-Component to display a tree view on my application. But once on a node I need to get the list of all children under that node and their children too.

I saw that they have a function on their documentation doForAll that is invoked for every node under the node I'm in.

[https://rawgit.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/master/doc/interfaces/*api*.itreenode.html#doforall](https://rawgit.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/master/doc/interfaces/_api_.itreenode.html#doforall)

I can call that function and it works fine when I do a console.log, but when I try to push the ID of my node to my array I only get the first element.

```
  getChildren(node: TreeNode) {
     node.doForAll((data) => {
         console.log(data.id);
         this.guideArray.push(data.id);
     });
     console.log(this.guideArray);
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: try moving the last console.log immediately after the push - inside the loop and see if it works then.. Not sure, but possibly 'this' inside doForAll may be different to 'this' when command completed. Let me know your findings! May need some sort of bind command.

Comment: @JGFMK When I move the console.log after I push to the array I can see on the console its pushing the ID, but when I expand the array [0] I can see all the elements

Comment: Can you insert screenshot of that into question. Perhaps just duplicate line rather than move too - And on last one do console.log("Final: ", this.guideArray);

Comment: I think @cyrix hit the nail on the head... Was not to do with 'this', so much as asynchronous code.

Comment: So it seems to have flattened the result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the `console.log` after you invoked the method isn't aware of the latest array state. That's because the implementation of `doForAll` is using a Promise, which is asynchronious. So the `console.log` command doesn't log the latest state.

You could create an `BehaviorSubject` with the all nodes like this:

```
getChildren(node: TreeNode) {
     let nodeIds$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
     node.doForAll((data) => {
         nodeIds$.next(nodeIds$.getValue().concat(data.id));
     });
     return nodeIds$;
}
```

See: [implementation of doForAll](https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/blob/master/lib/models/tree-node.model.ts#L213)

Comment: I just saw this.

Comment: thanks for the help, one quick question, with the BehaviorSubject that the function return is it possible to wait for it to finish so I can get all the data at once? I tried using the .finally function but it never gets executed. I kind need the data all at once

Comment: Is it possible to get parentid and position of the node?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else still looking for a way to find get child IDS at all levels synchronously under the parent node, you can use the below function that will get the data all at once synchronously:

```js
getAllChildrenIDs(node: TreeNode) {
 let arraywithIDs: number[] = [];
 if (node.hasChildren) {
  node.children.forEach((node1: TreeNode) => {
    arraywithIDs.push(node1.id);
    console.log('child level: ', node1.level);
    console.log(node1);
    arraywithIDs = arraywithIDs.concat(this.getAllChildrenIDs(node1));
   });
 }
 return arraywithIDs;
}
```